# AJAX call fails depending on position in code, browser fires document.ready mid-call. Twitter Bootstrap issue?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, document-ready

I am chasing a nasty issue. An AJAX call in an onclick handler does not complete, as the browser fires document.ready mid-call. When tracing the readystate and status in the Firebug console I get:

- `READYSTATECHANGE:1 STATUS:0`
- `READYSTATECHANGE:2 STATUS:0`
- `READYSTATECHANGE:4 STATUS:0`
- `Document Ready` (-> this is the
  second firing, breaking everything as the UI is rewired )

I believe I am not facing a cross-domain security block as the same AJAX call will complete correctly when called elsewhere in the page.

I am using Jquery 1.8.1 and I have tried multiple variations of AJAX client calls (i.e.

```
$.getJSON
$.ajax
```

as well as using the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Has anyone seen this before? Pointers for deeper debugging would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

After having debugged the issues I now have a work around. My AJAX call was invoked from a click handler linked to a Twitter Bootstrap Button. Clicking the button triggered the AJAX call but also a `window.load` event, which refreshed the JS application.

My work around was to replace the `<button>..</button>` with an `<input>..</input>` field, see below:

```
<form class="form-search">
    <label>Enter search string:
        <input id="SearchString" type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
        <!-- Broken: <button id="SearchAction" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Search </button> -->
        <!-- This works: -->
        <input type="button" id="SearchAction" value="Go Find"/>
        <img id="RssAction" style="vertical-align:bottom" src="images/feed-icon-14x14.png">
    </label>
</form>
```

This may not be the root cause yet.